# CSS Background image not showing on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, background-image

I have the following CSS code to show the background image:

```
body { background-image:url('../images/background.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-attachment:fixed; background-position:center; }
```

It does show in the browsers Chrome and Safari and it also shows on the iPhone (iOS 7.0). But when I load the page on my iPad (still running the iOS 6) it doesn't show the background image.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What are the dimensions (width and height in pixels) of `background.png` ?

Comment: 1000px x 704px @Shiva

Comment: Ok, then I think the size is not the problem. Check out the 1st few Stackoverflow search results from this search query. Some of them mention that the size was the issue (not in your case though I think) and others have said that it was due to ipad hardware acceleration issue, and they've used some webkit- directive to get around it. Hope this helps: https://www.google.com/search?q=ipad+background-image%3Aurl+not+working